# Kohana 3.2 - ORM's pk() methods returns false after save() (create()) - why?

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, kohana

I'm using Postgre 9 and I am connecting to it via PDO. I used schema from auth-schema-postgresql.sql, so tables should be fine.

I'm doing something like that:

```
$post = $this->request->post();
$member = new Model_User(); // ORM::factory('user');s
$member->create_user($post, array('email', 'username', 'password'));
```

Model user is  nothing fancy

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User {



    protected $_table_columns = array(
        'id'    => NULL,
        'email'  => NULL,
        'username'  => NULL,
        'password'  => NULL,
        'logins'  => NULL,
        'last_login'  => NULL
    );

} // End User Model
```

The problem is the id value in $member->object() equals false after save (same for pk() and $member->id). Row is being created fine, it has it's id, but I'd very like to have that number given by the pk() method.

Comment: What do you mean by "_$member->object() equals false_"? What exactly do you compare with what? And in what way (strict, like `===`, or not, like `==`)?

Comment: not $member->object() equals false, but id value in it.
$values = $member->object();
var_dump($values['id']); // prints bool(false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PDO you must supply the name of the Sequence object associated to the primary key of the table User. It would probably be user_id_sequence.
Navigate to the file "modules/database/classes/Kohana/Database/PDO.php". In the following lines of code (188-196):

```
elseif ($type === Database::INSERT)
    {
        // Return a list of insert id and rows created
        return array(
            $this->_connection->lastInsertId(),
            $result->rowCount(),
        );
    }
```

The name of the sequence object must be passed as an argument of the $this->_connection->lastInsertId() method as in the following:

```
elseif ($type === Database::INSERT)
    {
        // Return a list of insert id and rows created
        return array(
            $this->_connection->lastInsertId($sequence_name),
            $result->rowCount(),
        );
    }
```

This way, the ORM model can "be aware" of the new record's id auto-incremented by the sequence and therefore the pk() method will work fine.